# Word-meaning understanding (From Magoosh Flashcard--'Diffident')

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-meaning

Here's the definition of "Diffident":

> Showing modest reserve; lacking self-confidence

**Question:** Does "modest reserve" suggest a negative meaning?

Indeed, it seems irrelevant to the word "diffident" itself, but what came to my mind is that "modest reserve" seems to suggest negatively  "lack of confident" when I saw the definition of "Diffident." However, after I looked up the word "modest" and "reserve" separately in Cambridge, it seemed otherwise to me since "modest" tends to have a positive meaning according to the dictionary. I'm quite confused about it.

For reference, definitions are shown below:

> (Modest) not usually talking about or making obvious your own abilities and achievements

> (Reserve) the habit of not showing your feelings or thoughts

Comment: No, I would not interpret _modest reserve_ negatively. Incidentally, I think you must hve copied the definition out wrongly: "lacking of self-confident" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ColinFine Indeed, it should have been lacking self-confident. But according to Magoosh interpretation, it says "diffident" also has the meaning of modest reserve, and I think diffident has a negative meaning. So does it suggest "diffident" doesn't have to be negative or did I misinterpret it?

Comment: No, _diffident_ is not necessarily negative. And _lacking self-confident_ is still ungrammatical.

Comment: @ColinFine Indeed... "lacking self-confidence" would be correct. Thank you for pointing it out! So... how do you think about these two words, "modest reserve" and "diffident"?

Comment: I don't understand the question, @Eric.

Comment: @ColinFine Ahhh... sorry for my bad grammar but what I should have asked is
how do you interpret these two words, "modest reserve" and "diffident"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Diffident" can be used with either a negative or a positive implication. Indeed, two different people can both use it of the same third person, and one ise it positively and the other negatively. That is, both Bob and Sam might describe  Pat as diffident, but Bob means thsi in a negative way, while Same means it as positive.

Probably the most common meaning of "diffident" is "lacking in self-confidence". This is often but not always seen in a negative light, but usually only as   slightly negative

However a person might be described as "diffident" when  the person does not put himself (or herself) forward, is unassuming. In this sense it would be the opposite of "brash" or "aggressive". This sense would be considered by some as positive, and by others as negative. I think this sense is what is meant by "modest reserve".

Complicating the issue is that the external signs of these two senses are similar, so a person might be described as "diffident" in one sense when the othe would be more accurate.

In sort, context is required to determine if "diffident" is being used in a negative or positive way.

Comment: Thank you for ur careful explanation. I feel like learning languages is really not an easy work... you can use the same word to express either positive or negative or simply neutral tone.